# jquery cant find detect display:none if span/div uses class only works with style

Tags: jquery

i have a var called htmltext which has htmlcode assigned to it as you can see, it has multiple div/span containers some are using style some are using class and then some of them are using display:none.

I am then running a check for each span/div container to read the display attr and what its set to, however its only returning results for ones which use style and not class.

http://jsfiddle.net/hpqzb21j/2/

```
    $("#button5").click(function (event) {

        var htmltext = '<span><style>.ESkP{display:none}.GlJO{display:inline}.ghvd{display:none}.epK7{display:inline}.qwyK{display:none}.tCh3{display:inline}.BsEK{display:none}.e16T{display:inline}</style><span class="BsEK">60</span><span class="epK7">200</span>.<span class="GlJO">68</span><span class="BsEK">83</span><div style="display:none">83</div><div style="display:none">199</div>.<span class="76">24</span><span class="tCh3">.</span><span style="display:none">63</span><span></span><span style="display:none">65</span><div style="display:none">65</div><span style="display:none">85</span><span></span><span class="GlJO">107</span><span style="display:none">219</span><span></span><span style="display:none">241</span><div style="display:none">241</div></span>';

        $data = $('<span/>').html(htmltext);

        $data.find("div,span > span").each(function() {
            temp_display = $(this).css('display');
            console.log("display status = " + temp_display + " | text in container = "+ $(this).text());
        });

    });
```

the following is what the var htmltext is set to, so you can read it better, as it has to be all on one line above.

```
<span>

<style>
.ESkP{display:none}
.GlJO{display:inline}
.ghvd{display:none}
.epK7{display:inline}
.qwyK{display:none}
.tCh3{display:inline}
.BsEK{display:none}
.e16T{display:inline}
</style>

<span class="BsEK">60</span>
<span class="epK7">200</span>
.
<span class="GlJO">68</span>
<span class="BsEK">83</span>
<div style="display:none">83</div>
<div style="display:none">199</div>
.
<span class="76">24</span>
<span class="tCh3">.</span>
<span style="display:none">63</span>
<span></span>
<span style="display:none">65</span>
<div style="display:none">65</div>
<span style="display:none">85</span>
<span></span>
<span class="GlJO">107</span>
<span style="display:none">219</span>
<span></span>
<span style="display:none">241</span>
<div style="display:none">241</div>

</span>
```

below is the output i get,

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml.
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 60
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 200
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 68
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 83
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 83
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 199
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 24
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = .
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 63
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 
2fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 65
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 85
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 107
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 219
fiddle.jshell.net:30display status =  | text in container = 
2fiddle.jshell.net:30display status = none | text in container = 241
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:visible` pseudo-selector to check if element is visible.

```
is_visible = $(this).is(':visible');
```

If you want to check if element is not visible, you can use `:hidden`

```
is_hidden = $(this).is(':hidden');
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried this also, and when i use either of them it reports back the same result for every one. if i use visible i get 'false' for every one, and if i use hidden i get true for everyone. please see : http://jsfiddle.net/hpqzb21j/4/

Comment: @Skydiver1977 https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hpqzb21j/5/ You first have to put `html` in DOM

Comment: thank you. im on a pretty step learning curve. i noticed you appended this to the body, how will this impact me running many of these as i am reading in a table and the second cell contains variations of html text, so i am running tr:nth-child(2) in a .each function and resetting htmltext to the next and so on.